# Is it okay to lie to avoid hanging out with opposite gender?

Tags: sin, relationships, lying, friendship

Assalamu'Alaikum,

Before I was religious, I was friends with many people of the opposite gender (non-muslim).

However I have become more religious (Alhumdullilah) and realise it is not permitted in Islam to be friends with opposite gender

The friend group I am part of is full of non-muslims boys/girls and they regularly hangout.

I usually make excuses (such as I am busy with other things) and in rare cases lying to avoid hanging out. Is this permisable?

I have been friends with them for a very long time (5 - 8 years), I'm hoping that eventually they will stop inviting me

Jazakallah Khayrun

Comment: Assalamu alykom wa rahmut allah wa barakatu (peace be upon muslims). Indeed, you shall not be friends with opposite genders as there might be a chance that the Shaytan might force you into zina and eeyathu bellah (astaghfirullah). Moreover, remember that obeying and fearing Allah is much more important than earthly pleasures like having friends and hanging out and these time consuming stuff. Jazaka allah khayran!

Comment: @Kamola  wa'iyyak yes that is indeed my plan, I want to stay away from being friends with opposite genders, but in some situations I am having to lie to them to avoid hanging out, I am wondering if this is permitted to lie in such scenarios or how else can I respond to them? I have been friends with them for a long time so I am finding this a bit difficult

Comment: Dear brother, Rasuul allah salla allah aalyhe wa salam once permitted one of his believers to murder one of the mushrakeen poets who was voicing again the beloved prophet and even though that believer was close friends with that mushrik, the prophet instructed the believer to lie/deceive that mushrik before that believer grabbed his sword and strike his head.

Comment: @Kamola Source? That sounds like a completely different scenario to my scenario

Comment: Refer to this article brother, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ka%27b_ibn_al-Ashraf

Comment: @Kamola How does this scenario related to my case? Ka'b had insulted Allah's messenger pbuh. This scenario is completely different to mine - If anything this seems like a war scenario? And I have read that in war-scenario it is permitted to lie

Comment: It is not lawful to lie except in three cases: Something the man tells his wife to please her, to lie during war, and to lie in order to bring peace between the people.(Jami` at-Tirmidhi 1938) and also A liar is not one who tries to bring reconciliation amongst people and speaks good (in order to avert dispute), or he conveys good.(sahih Muslim). These are the baselines through which we derive applications to our lives. It very much depends on the person and scenario, so further consideration is needed.

Comment: @ahmadnazeem your comment looks like an answer in the comment section please avoid this

Comment: @Jamila it was posted as such because of the on going argument and i agree with you, point noted. will try to avoid such instances, in sha Allah. jazaakallah.